# Variance of three possible outcomes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, random-variables

I am new to this kind of things so maybe you could help me get the reasoning. I have a continuum of outcomes on the interval $[0,1]$. Now, let us cut the interval into two pieces so that there are two possible outcomes, $A$ and $B$, where the fraction of $A$ is $a$ and fraction of $B$ is $(1-a)$. In my book it is written that the variance of outcomes is 
$$
a(1-a)(A-B)^2. 
$$
Now let me introduce a third outcome $C$, so that we have outcomes $A$, $B$ and $C$ in proportions $a$, $b$ and $(1-a-b)$. Do you have any idea how to calculate the variance of outcomes now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let it be that random variable $X$ takes values in $\{A,B,C\}\subset[0,1]$ with probabilities $a$ (for $A$), $b$ (for $B$) and $c$ (for $C$). This with $a+b+c=1$.

Then $E(X)=aA+bB+cC$ and $E(X^2)=aA^2+bB^2+cC^2$ and $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! I think I make a naive mistake but when I use this method for the two variate case, A with prob a and B with prob (1-a). Then $Var(X)=-2a(1-a)AB$, and not $a(1-a)(A-B)^2$ as given in the book example, no?

Comment: if $a+b=1$  then $aA^2+bB^2-(aA+bB)^2=a(1-a)A^2-2abAB+b(1-b)B^2$ and here $1-a=b$ and $1-b=a$ so it leads to: $ab(A^2-2AB+B^2)=ab(A-B)^2=a(1-a)(A-B)^2$

Comment: Thanks! Simple mistakes I made

Comment: Very recognizable. You are definitely not the only one in this.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question on the basis of the comment from drhab (thanks). The variance is $$E(X^2) - E(X)^2$$, which in this setting is $$aA^2 + b B^2 - (-1 + a + b) C^2 - (a (A - C) + b (B - C) + C)^2$$.